# Why does IntelliSense not offer Dispose on DataTableReader?

Tags: .net, vb.net, intellisense, dispose, using

Essentially, I have a `DataTableReader` object and I was reviewing my code to make sure everything disposable was indeed disposed of.

`DataTableReader` implements `IDisposable`, but IntelliSense doesn't seem to be picking up on it:

[image]

It does however work with other disposable classes, such as `FileStream`:

[image]

So, what gives? `DataTableReader` *IS* disposable, right?

Comment: It is intentionally hidden.  It inherits Dispose() from its base class, DbDataReader.  Most classes that derive from it do have something to dispose, like SqlDataReader, since there is an actual dbase connection involved.  But DataTableReader does not, DataTable is all memory.

Comment: @HansPassant So Disposing of DataTableReader is pointless?

Comment: It does nothing.  Lots of programmers never knowingly called Dispose() yet, we tend to eventually hear from them at SO.  Lots of programmers prefer always calling Dispose() because they don't know what it does and they were bitten before.  Some programmers avoid writing pointless code.  Just stay out of the first group and you'll never have to be sorry.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the clarification. The programmers that came before me belonged to club A. The suggestion was to join club B, but I have too many of these to fix, so club C sounds just right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `DbDataReader`'s `Dispose` method has the [EditorBrowsableAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) set to Never basically telling VS to not show it. Why? I am not sure.

```
[EditorBrowsableAttribute(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public void Dispose() {
    Dispose(true);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    if (disposing) {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DbDataReader.cs,f7c2de36229de361

Answer (score 0):

DotPeek reveals this for `DbDataReader`, the parent class of DataTableReader:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public void Dispose()
```

So that's why...